# How do I prove something is single-valued and total?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Question**

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be functions. Define $h\subseteq\ X\times Z$ by

$h\left(x\right)=z$ iff there is a $y\in Y$ such that $f\left(x\right)=y$ and $g\left(y\right)=z$

Show that $h$ is a function.

**What I have so far:**

To show h is a function we need to show that it is both single-valued and total, i.e. if $\left(x,y\right),\left(x,z\right)\in h$ then $y=z$ and for each $x\in X$, there is a $z\in Z$ such that $\left(x,z\right)\in h$. As $h\left(x\right)=z$, $h\left(x\right)=g\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$.

I understand what I have to do to find out if it is a function (single-valued and total) but I don't exactly know how to get there. Can someone point me in the right direction of where to go to start this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$h$ is single-valued:
Suppose $(x, z_1), (x, z_2)\in h$. Let $y_1, y_2\in Y$ be such that $z_1=g(y_1)$, $y_1=f(x)$, $z_2=g(y_2)$, $y_2=f(x)$. Since $f$ is single-valued, $y_1=y_2$. Then $z_1=z_2$ as $g$ is single-valued.

$h$ is total:
Suppose $x\in h$. Let $z=g(f(x))$. Then for $y=f(x)$, we have both $z=g(y)$ and $y=f(x)$. Thus, by definition, $(x, z) \in h$.

Comment: I'm guessing from the OP's wording of this Question that this implication is not clear.  I'd recommend treating the "single-valued" and "total" properties separately in answering.

Comment: Not really tbh I understand logically what that all means but don't see where that implies either single-valuedness or totality.

Comment: @KingBottleCapp I've edited in more details